# SPF records had no effect to email displays [Gmail]

Tags: email

I have recently implemented SPF records on my domain. However, the emails that come from our instance still show "via ..." bit.

The SPF record is:

`v=spf1 a mx ip4:1....4 ip4:204.14.234.97 ip4:204.14.234.98 ip4:204.14.234.99 ip4:204.14.234.100 include:_spf.google.com include:vresp.com include:verticalresponse.com include:salesforce.com ~all`

The email comes in as:

`Derp Dzh via lk****oyy0.3-jhp**ae.na13.bnc.salesforce.com`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Hi, This question is not really a SF issue. Either try to be more specific of the issue, or ask it to be moved. I don't see how you will get an answer to this in SFSE.

Comment: Actually, this is related to SFSE, because they want to know how to "get rid" of the "via" message on emails sent from salesforce.com. They implemented SPF on their domain, but the via reference still appears.

Comment: They do have bunch of kbase articles about it, there are few threads here about it. I do not see how it is not related. I could be some mistake from dns perspective, but the trouble is I did test sending from a local SMTP server and didn't have any problems. So. Perhaps I should whitelist more ip addresses?

Answer (score 2):

THE ISSUE IS NO DKIM and/or incorrect salesforce include!
They both work together!

I know this is an old post but someone will find it again.

For the SPF use "include:_spf.salesforce.com" in your SPF record (not just salesforce.com)
Setup DKIM:
Type DKIM into the salesforce setup quick find
create a new DKIM record, (there are a number of ways but this way is sure fire)
Create New.
Selector = "salesforce"
Domain = {your domain}
Domain Match = Exact Domain Only.
Now create a DKIM TXT record in your Zone file with your DNS provider.
It should look like this:

```
salesforce._domainkey TXT v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DKUGVYGVQUAA4GNADCBiQUHBuUHViuvyf3mZZojdjJtrTC8pPmTHolBGP+PygWinwFxYgII2Ua/6pwJ9KnT3faG7LFldfb7dfb78fb90FLieqqJ8A851NczBKj8p93DFiU1IWSC15FrKTvEJBmC5Zyni9TbEpzfVLuHB3/2QUdQsdfv87d7Ent3U79Pf+Aocv+Fkwru6Psdf7v8wIDAQAB
```

The Salesforce DKIM setups resulting Public Key is pasted into the Zone File TXT records Data field.

Now activate the DKIM you setup.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Google Apps for your domain for sending email?  If so, just a heads up that the salesforce.com email relay feature doesn't support SMTP authentication, which is required by Google Apps.

Comment: Internally, yes - we use Google Apps, but emails from Salesforce use Salesforce SMTP servers.